# XAMPP + Windows 7 + ImageMagick = Impossible?

Tags: windows, imagemagick

For some reason, over the past year I have tried to install imagemagick on my windows 7 machine running with XAMPP server (a LAMP package for windows) and I have failed every single try to the point that I think it is impossible, some people claim to have done it but I have yet to see it with my own eyes, I have tried every tutorial, user directions, instructions, you name it.  WHy is it nearly impossible?

Comment: The L in LAMP stands for Linux, and it's XAMPP not Xammp. What role does ImageMagick have in this? BTW, you posted this question on SF only a few days ago, but there were no answers. Maybe you should accept that's it's impossible, or at least accept that others think so.

Comment: That makes no sense, imagemagick provides an EXE Windows version of there software so I do not see how it is really impossible.  Also even though this site has the same own, same code, and same functionality and is part of a family of question and answer sites does not mean that people from the other member sites view all the sites.  SO basicly someone on this site may see my very very valid question that would not have seen it on the other site.

Comment: Is what impossible?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be your issues so far stemmed from permission issues? What exactly did you experience? You need to provide more information about your problem, rather than just that "it's nearly impossible" :)

I've used XAMPP on 7 with no problems. Haven't used ImageMagick, but from a short review of the site, it looks doable. Just download the PHP implementation ([MagickWand](http://www.magickwand.org/)) or the  Perl one if you prefer, put in a directory accessible by Apache and have a go.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Look this [manual](http://howto.memcrab.com/2012/11/windows-xampp-18-imagick.html). It's russian, but links correct.